# Ubuntu 19.10 Firefox can't play DRM content

Tags: firefox, video, drm

I use Ubuntu 19.10 for 2 weeks now and I like it so far except that I have one little problem: The per-installed Firefox does not allow me to play DRM content media (and possible other media too).

i.e.

- I cant play Spotify in Firefox. It gives me a DRM error.
- Some youtube videos won't play giving me this error: [screenshot YouTube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HwSR.png)
- I also try to watch recorded lectures from my university but there too I get an error... I dont think the university uses DRM content [screenshot videoplayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJCsj.png)

Widevine by google and OpenH264 are both installed and DRM content is enabled in settings.

So I suspect it has to do with HTML5 video, anyone knows a fix?

Comment: Is DRM enabled in FF settings?

Comment: Yes. It is enabled

Comment: Can you play videos in Chrome?

Comment: Just installed Chromium. Youtube works, university video's work but spotify did not work. With spotify I still see the DRM error, even though it is enabled in Chromium settings

Comment: I suggest installing Chrome. Many sites don't support FF.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option for me. I ditched Chrome a long time ago. On Windows everything worked fine, never had an error. So I don't think it is website related like you suggest.

Comment: I can't watch videos with FF on EurosportPlayer, but can with Chrome.

Comment: Until 19.04, I had no problem using Netflix on Ubuntu/Firefox. After an upgrade to 19.10, it stopped working, even when after enabling "Play DRM-controlled content" in Firefox :-( NB: Netflix gives the following error https://help.netflix.com/en/node/105186

Answer (score 6):

Run the following commands

```bsh
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

then restart Firefox. Solved the problem for me on Spotify and Netflix.

Credits goes to this Reddit post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/e4mc98/firefox_cant_play_drm_content_on_ubuntu_1910/

Answer (score 0):

What solved this problem for me was to stop the tracking blocker. Enabled DRM content and still wouldn't play, then realized the tracking blocker was enabled and stopped that, and everything plays. SO: enable DRM content in the settings, then disable the tracking blocker, and you should be fine. There's no difference between FF and chrome as far as DRM content is concerned, per se.

Answer (score 0):

I needed only this command (part of [Pierre-Antoine's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199521/527764)):

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a customized linux kernel, check the `CONFIG_SECCOMP` option. It should be enabled.